# Dynamically add parameters to Powershell cmdlet

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

**BACKGROUND**
I have the cmdlet Send-MailMessage, it uses a dynamically generated HTML file as the body and an XML file for all other config.

The XML file looks like this:

> ```
> <root>
>     ...
>     <Emails>
>         <Email id="statsEmail" SMTPSvr="mailrelay@domain.com">
>             <config>
>                 <from>lab@domain.com</from>
>                 <to>techgroup@domain.com</to>
>                 <to>techgroup1@domain.com</to>
>                 <cc>iWantItToo@domain.com</cc>
>                 <bcc>manager@domain.com</bcc>
>                 <subject>Statistics</subject>
>             </config>
>         </Email>
>         ...
>     </Emails>
> </root>
> ```

And if I invoke it with Powershell like this:
    $config = $configXML.selectNodes("//Email[@id="statsEmail"]")

```
Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer $config.SMTPSvr `
    -From $config.From `
    -To $config.To -Cc $config.Cc -Bcc $config.Bcc `
    -Subject $config.Subject `
    -Attachments $attachArray `
    -BodyAsHtml "$SCRIPT:htmlBody"
```

It works just fine..

**ISSUE**
If the manager then decides he no longer wants to be BCCed in, I just remove the BCC element from the config file right? WRONG, Powershell (quite rightly) throws an error because I’m specifying the BCC param and $config.bcc is about as $null as it gets.

Here's the error (just incase someone asks):

> Send-MailMessage : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Cc'. The argument is null or empty. Supply an argument that is not null or empty and then try the command again.
>           + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Send-MailMessage], ParameterBindingValidationException

**CONCLUDE**
I realise I could solve this by putting Send-MailMessage in a nested if, I'm just curious if there's a cleaner solution to add/remove the Cc & Bcc params dynamically.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Create a hashtable with all of the parameters and values that you want to send to the cmdlet, and then "[splat](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj672955.aspx)" it.  This will give you programmatic control over the parameters and values that get sent in, and display them in an easy-to-read (for humans) format, like in the following example:

```
# Define the parameters and values to give to Send-MailMessage.
$parameters = @{
    From = $config.From
    ...
    To   = $config.To
}

# Check if $config.BCC is null. If it isn't, add it to the hashtable.
if ($null -ne $config.Bcc) {
    $parameters.Add("BCC", $config.Bcc)
}

# Call Send-MailMessage with all of our prepared parameters.
Send-MailMessage @parameters
```

Comment: If you want to dynamically add a switch parameter, set the value to `$true` like, for example `Sort-Object` has the `Descending` switch parameter. This example would be like `$parameters.Add("Descending", $true)`.